# Page specific css not loading

Tags: css, vue.js, nativescript

I use nativescript with VueJs

My problem is that my [page specified CSS](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#page-specific-css) files aren't used.

My start page is `start.js` and in the same folder I have a `start.css`
but the styles aren't applied.

Do I need to something else, or configure? 
Because at the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#page-specific-css) I said that it normally should work like this.

[image: Folder layout]

Comment: May I know which flavour you are using for your project. You have tagged with Vue but your screenshot looks like a Core JS project.

Comment: @Manoj I'm using Webstorm [this is how](https://imgur.com/a/eZodBA0) I created that project with VueJS

Comment: You will need to _paste_ the contents of your `start.js` file (no more screenshots, please). Simply having a file in the directory with the same prefix doesn't automatically link the two.

Comment: Honestly don't understand why your question was downvoted; upvoted it. Also, added another answer that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always refer the appropriate docs for the flavour, since you are using Vue you must follow the [docs here](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/introduction/). What you were referring to was for core js one.

With NativeScript Vue you have to write scoped styles within your component, just the same way how you would do it for a Vue based web app.

Comment: Thanks I thought that also should work for VueJs because something thing from the core also work for VueJs

Comment: In a way you are correct, Core is the base for everything. But it also matters when you apply them / what the `nativescript-vue` package does internally (it should not overwrite what you are applying). So its best to stay with your framework features when we use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

An external file can be used as Page-Specific CSS as follows in NativeScript-Vue:

```
<style scoped src="./Home.css"></style>
```

Where, **`Home.css`** is located in your **`components`** folder.

Similarly, for SCSS:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped src="./Home.scss"></style>
```

Note: You'll need to rebuild your app by if its running on an emulator/device when you make this addition to your .Vue file.